# Android Keyboard with number and decimal for LG G4

Tags: android, android-layout, keyboard

I am using the following element in the Android **EditText**, to have a keyboard with number and decimal for displaying a keyboard layout for **amount input** (*for eg 22.12*).

```
android:inputType="numberDecimal"
```

It is working for all devices, like Samsung, Nexus, Sony etc.

The keyboard layout looks like below. [image: Nexus keyboard Layout]

The keyboard layout on the LG G4 looks like below.[image: LG G4 keyboard Layout]

Could anyone please help, how to have decimal keyboard for the LG G4. I have already tried the `android:inputType="phone"`, still same issue.

I would like to stick to the decimal input, as it would not be very nice to have a full alpha-numeric keyboard, to enter amount.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Same problem here with LG K10 Android 6.0.

Answer (score 6):

**UPDATE**
It seems that flag signed is not needed after all to get decimal separator, It was actually the TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_NO_SUGGESTIONS that messed up the keyboard so do not use it with number input types. Also noticed that LG keyboard looks different depending on if you set the input type from code vs. XML
**END UPDATE**

It seems like the combination of inputType and digits solves the problem. I have a class that extends EditText so I initialize the EditText like this:

```
setKeyListener(DigitsKeyListener.getInstance("0123456789.,"));
setRawInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER | InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_DECIMAL | InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_SIGNED);
```

I guess that because LG has bundled decimal separator and minus sign in a same button you have to configure both feature on and then disable "-" by not including it in digits.

Comment: Also, the order matters. If you `setRawInputType()` before `setKeyListener()` you lose the dot.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 possible ways i can think of, but i do not have an LG make phone, so i personally couldn't test any of these. But still its worth a shot.

1. Try to give the input type as `android:inputType="phone"`. 
   Saw this on the dev site, more details here https://developer.android.com/training/keyboard-input/style.html#Type
2. This one i tried a couple of years back, it worked for me, but my case was different. Specify an attribute in your EditText item in xml.

   android:digits="0123456789."

What it does is, sets the view to accept numeric input and only the specific items mentioned in the digits attribute. I personally do not use it much, its more of a hack than a solution, but it gets things done. More info on the below link:

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html

Try these out, hope they help for all cases.

Comment: @B.B, am very sorry.. saw that you have already tried with 
android:inputType="phone"
Kindly, try and implement with the second option in my answer.

Comment: `android:digits="0123456789,."` is already in place. Doesn't work.