# Android Custom EditText Numbers

Tags: android, android-layout, samsung-mobile, android-keypad

In my application I've EditText-Fields, which should be able to hold decimal numbers.  So my keyboard should show all numbers, the comma, the point and the minus sign, in order to type in currency-values. I defined the EditText-Field through the following InputTypes:

```
InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER | InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_DECIMAL | InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_SIGNED
```

So this works for almost all of the Android Devices, but just recently I discovered a strange behavior with Samsung A3(2017) devices:

[image: displayed keyboard]

As you can see, the keyboard only gives the option to type in natural numbers.

Data of the testdevice:

- Phone: Galaxy A3 (2017)
- Android Version: 8.0.0
- Samsung Experience Version: 9.0
- Keyboard: Samsung Keyboard
- MDM-Managed Device: Yes (KNOX)

I installed Google's GBoard keyboard and the numpad showed up as wanted, with dots and commas. But I can't just hope for consumers downloading different keyboard, if samsung keyboard is not working. Any ideas how to fix this problem?

I implemented my CustomEditText as statet in this thread:
[Android Keyboard with number and decimal for LG G4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37721694/android-keyboard-with-number-and-decimal-for-lg-g4)

Comment: Take a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40507863/323149

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Keyboard with number and decimal for LG G4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37721694/android-keyboard-with-number-and-decimal-for-lg-g4)

Comment: Asking that question, I've seen the other thread before, but due to the fact, that Samsung has it's own little stumbling stones and the other thread is over 2 years old, I tried to seek help here.

Anyway, I've already tried to set android:inputType as 'numberDecimal' and 'phone. 

And I'm initializing my EditText as suggested in the other thread anyway:

setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER | InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_DECIMAL | InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_SIGNED);
setKeyListener(DigitsKeyListener.getInstance("0123456789.,"));